# Coroutines in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

**Context:** I am writing a `Django` script as shown below. To my knowledge, the loop below will block the `Django` app and prevent other processes from running(ex. request handlers).

**Problem:** What should I do so `Django` will ***run*** the following loop and ***yield*** to run other scripts when they are triggered. When said scripts are completed, the loop will ***resume*** on the same index.

```
# ./app.py

while True:
    items = queryItems()
    for item in items:
        process(item)
```

**Constraint:** The answer should work in `Python 2.7` and only uses libraries supporting `Python 2.7`.

Comment: It's been three years since you asked this question originally, but are you still working under the Python 2.7 constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

> To my knowledge, the loop below will block the Django app and prevent other processes from running(ex. request handlers).

This is partially true; the loop will block your *current* request until it has completed, however it won't block other requests from happening concurrently (from other clients). Each request that comes in will be executed in a separate worker process.

> What should I do so Django will run the following loop and yield to run other scripts when they are triggered.

I think what you're asking here is "how can I run `process(item)` asynchronously/in parallel?". Django doesn't come with anything that can run tasks in parallel like that out of the box. If you want to wait until all the processing has completed before returning a response, you could use a multithread/multiprocess approach. Another option is to use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is an asynchronous task runner that plugs nicely into django. Celery allows for task execution totally independent of the request/response cycle and has lots of nice features for checking the status of your tasks etc.

Comment: Do you mean that django will fork a process to handle each of the coming request?Can you show me the doc?