# Method is waiting for asyncio to complete before moving to next line

Tags: django, multithreading, django-views, python-asyncio

I am trying to use the `asyncio` in my code. This is working, but the problem is **I want my code to keep executing** instead it keep waiting for the `asyncio` code to complete execution.

In the current scenario my code keep waiting for the asyncio code `result = asyncio.run(run())` to complete before moving onto the next line of code.

**I think my asyncio code needs to be executed on the new thread. But how can I make it work?**

I am using Django.

```
def Dashboard(requests):
    result = asyncio.run(run())
    all_Farm = MyCollection.objects.all().filter(userid=requests.user.id)

    return render(requests, 'Dashboard.html',
                  {'all_farm': all_Farm})


async def run():

    drone = System()
    await drone.connect(system_address="udp://:14540")

    print("Waiting for drone to connect...")
    async for state in drone.core.connection_state():
        if state.is_connected:
            print(f"Drone discovered with UUID: {state.uuid}")
            break

    print("Waiting for drone to have a global position estimate...")
    async for health in drone.telemetry.health():
        if health.is_global_position_ok:
            print("Global position estimate ok")
            break

    print("-- Arming")
    await drone.action.arm()

    print("-- Taking off")
    await drone.action.takeoff()

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    print("-- Landing")
    await drone.action.land()
```

Comment: You should switch to a framework that supports asyncio.

Comment: Or use something similar to `System` that doesn't use asyncio.

Comment: Changing the framework is not an option for me. That will be helpful if I can get the solution within the current framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research on this topic of running async methods in Django, I found a solution that actually worked in my case.

The solution that I found is [CELERY](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/index.html). I found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726812/4728323).
Celery works perfectly fine along with Django.